# How to implement Rotation and Drag&Drop in Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, kineticjs, image-rotation

I need a code to do the follow things: I've an image definited to Kinetic.Image, and this image should rotate; I have to use the drag and drop on this image, but the rotation doesn't allow the drag and drop. Can you give me a code to do this? I searched some tutorials but they don't help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS images are both draggable and rotatable already.

[image]

For the "drop", you can listen for the drop event on the image like this:

```
  kImage.on('dragend', function() {

      // do your drop tests here

  });
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/eCekf/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var kImage;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        kImage=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:img,
            x:175,
            y:175,
            width:150,
            height:150,
            offset:[75,75],
            draggable:true
        });
        layer.add(kImage);
        kImage.rotate(30*Math.PI/180);
        layer.draw();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";


    $("#rotate").click(function(){
        kImage.rotate(kImage.getRotation()+20*Math.PI/180);
        layer.draw();
    });

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="rotate">Rotate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. But I meant a rotation as movement: the image moves on a circolar trajectory! Can you help me?

Comment: Sure, just change the offsets to rotate around any point you desire.  See my edited Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/eCekf/  This rotates around the image's initial x/y of 200,200.  If you drag the image to a new location, it will rotate around that new x/y.